# How to search Vendor Credit in Netsuite?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I used Suitetalk C# for getting data from Netsuite.

In my case, I need to pull Vendor Credit data to my app. So that, I created a search method, but I don't know how to apply search criteria like this :

1) I need to pull only unApplied Vendor Credit.

2) I need to pull only Applied Vendor Credit in a List of Vendor Bill.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If yes, please add some code. `I created a search method` <-- my assumption is that you want to add some functionality to this method, but not sure how. If yes, it's important for us to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would create a saved searches on transaction from UI

1) unApplied Vendor Credit

```
Applied to Transaction is -None-
```

2) 100% applied vendor credit
with criteria as

```
A) Formula (Numeric) {amount} + {appliedtolinkamount} is 0
 B) Applied to Link Amount is greater than 0.0
```

3) Applied (partially or fully)

```
Applied to Transaction is not -None-
```

On Each search you would want to enter filters like `type is Bill Credit` and `Main Line is true`

Then I would get the saved search Ids from UI and then use below pseudo code to get search results via SuiteTalk

```
// Create a service 
NetSuiteService nss = new NetSuiteService();

// Perform the search. Note that you can get the saved search ID using 
// either getSavedSearch() or through the UI
TransactionSearchAdvanced tsa1 = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();
tsa1.savedSearchId="57";  //substitute your own saved search internal ID
nss.search(tsa1);
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this ?
I have a block of code to Create a Payment for A Bill, but by default, it create a payment with full amount of bill, I just want to pay a half, can we do that ?

Comment: did you try editing the 'amount' field in line item 'apply'? Body level amount field wont change until this one changes